# convert from hex color to RGB

Tags: java, android, colors

How can I get RGB values from color in form "#6F00AC"?

I tried this but didn't worked

```
int newcolor = (int)Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#6F00AC")), 16);
    float r = ((newcolor >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255f;
    float g = ((newcolor >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255f;
    float b = ((newcolor >> 0) & 0xFF) / 255f;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) has the static methods red/blue/green and alpha

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#6F00AC");
int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);
int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
```

they return  respectively the red, blue, green, alpha component of a color int.

EDIT:

Your code is almost correct, (you don't need to divide by 255)

```
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = color & 0xFF;
```

Comment: what does it mean ? What did you get and what were you expecting ?

Comment: I edited my answer, your code was almost correct. The mistake was to divide by 255

Comment: I'm trying to get / 255f value. Your first one is good and I found that in my last code I have to pass the value like "6F00AC" without # and worked